# Segmentation fault when deleting a Array

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

I have simplified the following functions, when trying to delete the array after using it i get a segfault.

```
float * MyService::innerFunction(MyClass& feature) {
    float* target = new float[1];
    target[0] = feature.getValue();
    target[1] = 1;
    return target;
}

float MyService::outerFunction(MyClass& feature){
    float* input = innerFunction(feature);
    ...
    delete[] input; <- seg fault
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Congratulations, you've removed the part of the code with the bug in it.

Comment: sorry i (simplified) added the line which was causing the error... but somehow the segfault occurs on delete, not when setting the var

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: There's maybe an idea to use `std::array<float, 1>` with `std::unique_ptr` instead?

Comment: This isn't Java or c#. When you do undefined things then you get undefined behaviour. You cannot rely on it breaking at the point you get those things wrong.

Comment: For me there is no question left, i found the problem and learned the lesson that segfaults can occur delayed

Comment: Your array on the heap is only size 1. And you put two items in it after that. Needs to be "new float [2]". Probably not your problem, but still need to be changed.

Comment: You should show us the Valgrind output from a [mcve] (and explain how it fails to identify the cause) when asking about memory access errors such as this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is too small.
`float* target = new float[1];` allocates only one element but you assign two.
`target[1] = 1;` corrupts your head.

So you need to to do:

```
float* target = new float[2];
```